# Unable to acces the shared preferences from android:process:xxx to my Activity

Tags: android, process, sharedpreferences

In my application, I created android:process:xxx. I am trying to put a String value in preference from the process xxx components with the key of "name". After this  i am trying to get the value with same key from Activity. Activity is not belongs to process xxx.

I created my shared preference like below.

```
mPref = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
mEditor = mPref.edit();
```

Comment: MODE_MULTI_PROCESS may not work properly in 2.3 devices. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12144418/2688378

Comment: I am testing on 4.0+ versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two or more processes on your app, instead of shared preferences, create one table in your database. Save the values in that table.

Comment: This post might answer the question but a little more explanation will help out fellow programmers how it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
public SessionManager(Context context){
    this._context = context;
    //make mode as private
    pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = pref.edit();
}
```