# Save in SharedPreferences value returned from JavascriptInterface in webview

Tags: android, webview, sharedpreferences, android-context

I think taht's a `Context` problem, but I could not figure it out.

I'm retrieving a user id from webview with `JavascriptInterface` Interface. I'm using `WebAppInterface` class to retrieve the value and save it in sharedprefs. I could test the returned value and it's ok. It is saved in the SharedPreferences when I pull it from inside `WebAppInterface`but when I try to retrieve it in another activity the value retrieved is default.

The webview activity:

```
public class Login extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
        myWebView.loadUrl("mydomain.com/retrieveid"); //here I use the real url
    }
 ...
}
```

The WebAppInterfaceClass

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;
    SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        mPrefs = c.getSharedPreferences("My_Prefs", 0);
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void returnUserID(String uid) {
        Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("uid", Integer.valueOf(uid));
        editor.commit();
        Integer uid2 = mPrefs.getInt("uid", 0);
        Log.i("uid after update", String.valueOf(uid2)); //this value is correct
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
   }
}
```

Then in MainActivity.class I try to retrive this value with `getSharedPreferences("My_Prefs", 0).getInt("uid",0);` and it always return 0.

Comment: Do the 2 activities live in separate processes? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125214/shared-preferences-between-two-processes-of-the-same-application

Comment: I think that's the issue... I'll try it and update here.

Comment: See my updated answer. It looks like writing a ContentProvider or a Service is the right answer.

Comment: Please check two things:  1. Using the **ApplicationContext** 2. Use the c.getSharedPreferences("My_Prefs", **Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS**);
Try it. Hope it will help you fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Basically don't pass values between activities in SharedPreferences, that's what are Intent Extras are for.

The rough Idea is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("uid", uid);
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

and then in MainActivity

```
getIntent().getIntExtra("uid", -1);
```

will return your value or -1

2. It's a bit weird that you are triggering the MainActivity with an Intent from inside the app which makes me think you should actually have started the current activity with startActivityForResult: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: I'm not actually calling mainactivity.. That's just a sample. I'm using some variantes to redirect the user to 3 diferentes activities. I was using intents, but I need this uid in all activities and next time the uawr launch the app...

Comment: If you are using single process then my suggestion then is to create a SharedPrefs singleton, so you'll only have one instance of SharedPreferences and therefore also Memory updates (apply) will be enough.

Comment: I've passed the value as a Intent Extra to the other activity and saved it as a SharedPref there. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

[Updated]

## Scenario 1 - The 2 activities are in separate apps

When calling [getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String,%20int)), the `mode` argument determines whether the stored values are private, or globally readable and/or writeable.

[MODE_PRIVATE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_PRIVATE) (whose value 0) is probably what you used in the app that originally stored the data. That means that no other apps have any access to that data.

You should be aware that the other modes have been deprecated since API Level 17, though, since they open up security holes.

You should consider having the first app implement either a [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) or [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) to provide the shared data.

## Scenario 2 - The 2 activities are in the same app, but in different processes

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125214/shared-preferences-between-two-processes-of-the-same-application) and its accepted answer. Please note, though, that [MODE_MULTI_PROCESS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_MULTI_PROCESS) is deprecated in API level 23 as it does not work reliably in some versions of Android and does not attempt to reconcile concurrent modifications across processes.

You should consider implementing either a ContentProvider or Service to provide the shared data. For very simple data, a [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing.html) (a ContentProvider for files) might be sufficient.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain well but I'm calling within the same app. The webappinterface is a class in the same app.

Comment: OK, see my comment to your question.

Comment: I just need to save an integer. Maybe just wriring a file would be easier then a contente provider? What do you think?

Comment: A [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing.html) might work for you. I've added that to my answer.