# SharedPreferences of Remote service always return null

Tags: android, android-activity, service, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences

I have a trouble with `SharedPreferences` when I try read data from remote service.

**First**, In `SplashScreenActivity`, my app `start` and `bind` my `RemoteService`

**Second**, `SplashScreenActivity` start `MainActivity`, this `MainActivity` will save configuration info to `SharedPreferences`:

```
SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("ABC_KEY", "abc");
editor.apply();
```

**Then**, `MainActivity` will send `Broadcast`:

`sendBroadcast(new Intent("PLZ_READ_DATA"));`

**Finally**, in `RemoteService` receive above `Broadcast`, it will read data from `SharedPreferences`:

```
SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
String str = mSharedPreferences.getString("ABC_KEY", null);
```

The problem is `str` is always `null`.

What is the magic here? Can anyone explain it and give a solution for read data from `SharedPreferences` on this case.

Comment: is your remote service running in the same process? what happens if you add logs before and after, can you be sure the insertion happens first?

Comment: `RemoteService` will run in another process. I logged before and after writing data to `SharedPreferences`, everything works exactly, but the read process does not work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're dealing with multiple processes you need to specify the mode to support that as can be seen from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12144418/1056359)

Comment: Ok, thank you so much. I will try another way, because `MODE_MULTI_PROCESS `  has been deprecated in Android M.