# SharedPreferences not updating value in Android 6 and above

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm storing user's profile picture uri in SharedPreferences. When the user updates their profile image, it should get updated in SharedPreferences as well. However, when I try to retrieve the new image uri, I always get the old uri, but if I turn the device off or force the app to stop, the value is updated. I've noticed that this problem happens on android 6.0 and 8.0, tried kitkat and it works fine. I found some solutions on the internet that suggested using apply() instead of commit(),but neither worked.

Here's the code I use to save the image uri:

```
SharedPreferences login = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = login.edit();
editor.putString( USER_PROFILE_PIC,  selectedImage.toString());
editor.apply();
```

And here's how I retrieve the image uri:

```
SharedPreferences login = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = login.edit();
String profileImageURI = login.getString( USER_PROFILE_PIC, "" );
```

**Update**

The value is returned correctly in the activity where I update the SharedPreferences. However, in the syncAdapter, when I retrieve the value from SharePreferences, it returns the old value.

Comment: See if editor.commit() return true or false.

Comment: It's returning true @SuyashChavan

Comment: You can check the values inside SharedPreferences with by using com.willowtreeapps.hyperion:hyperion-shared-preferences lib. See if it gets updated to desired value

Comment: Did you try to log the value of the uri after retreiving it from sharedpreferences ?

Comment: Yes, I did, and it displays the old value. @takieddine

Comment: The SharePreferences file gets updated with the new value. However, when I use "getString", it returns the old value. The only explanation I could come up to, is that the value in RAM doesn't get updated with latest file value, please correct me if I'm mistaking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12144418/6651763), in `Android < 2.3`, one process can make changes, and the other one can read the changes. After `Android > 2.3`, this was still possible, but need to set `MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` when using `SharePreferences`, so the code becomes like this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName() + "_preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE| Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS); // context.getPackageName() + "_preferences" is the name of the sharePreferences file
```

And the I first found solution [in this blog](https://blog.catzie.net/android-sharedpreferences-not-accessible-from-syncadapter/)